# How to get differents values 'types' from table creating virtual columns - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have these tables.

**tb_employee**:

```
ID_EMP           NAME_EMP
1               Employee 1
2               Employee 2
3               Employee 3
4               Employee 4
```

**tb_requirements**:

```
ID_REQ                  DESCRIPTION_REQ               TYPE_REQ
1                        Requirement 1                   1
2                        Requirement 2                   1
3                        Requirement 3                   1
4                        Requirement 4                   2
5                        Requirement 5                   2
6                        Requirement 6                   2
7                        Requirement 7                   2
```

**tb_detail**:

```
ID_DET                        ID_EMP                        ID_REQ
1                               1                             1
2                               1                             2
3                               1                             4
4                               2                             1
5                               2                             6
6                               3                             4
7                               3                             7
```

I need to make a `SELECT QUERY` to count how many `requirements` each employee has got and which type, like this:

```
ID_EMP               NAME_EMP          TYPE_REQ1(virtual column)     TYPE_REQ2 (virt. c.)
1                    Employee 1               2                         4
2                    Employee 2               1                         1
3                    Employee 3               0                         2
4                    Employee 4               0                         0
```

I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: Proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle might help, TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT 
e.ID_EMP 
,e.NAME_EMP
,(CASE WHEN SUM(r.TYPE_REQ=1) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(r.TYPE_REQ=1) END ) TYPE_REQ1
,(CASE WHEN SUM(r.TYPE_REQ=2) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(r.TYPE_REQ=2) END ) TYPE_REQ2
FROM 
tb_employee e
LEFT JOIN tb_detail d ON (e.ID_EMP=d.ID_EMP)
LEFT JOIN  tb_requirements r ON (d.ID_REQ=r.ID_REQ)
GROUP BY e.ID_EMP
```

Comment: It's great ! BUT, this only shows the 'details' of the first employee (in this case `ID_EMP 1`) ... i'll try to modify the query

Comment: @JhonatanSandoval see my updated answer with left join

Comment: GREAT !! But now i see `NULL` in some rows, how can i set it as `0` ? I remember is like `IS NULL (SUM...)` ?